# Problem with Entity Framework 2.1 mapping

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, nopcommerce

I upgraded a plugin from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to .NET Core 2.1 and have problem with EF mapping.

I have class in 4.6.1 what extend base Picture class:

```
public partial class PictureExt : Picture
{
    public virtual string ExternalUrl { get; set; }
}
```

base class:

```
public partial class Picture : BaseEntity
{
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public string SeoFilename { get; set; }
    public string AltAttribute { get; set; }
    public string TitleAttribute { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
    public virtual PictureBinary PictureBinary { get; set; }
}
```

and in 4.6.1 I done mapping:

```
    public PictureMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Picture");
        this.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        this.Property(p => p.PictureBinary).IsMaxLength();
        this.Property(p => p.MimeType).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(40);
        this.Property(p => p.SeoFilename).HasMaxLength(300);
        this.Property(p => p.ExternalUrl).IsOptional();
    }
```

and all work great

but in .NET Core EF I done mapping:

```
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PictureExt> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Picture");
        builder.HasKey(picture => picture.Id);
        builder.Property(picture => 
        picture.MimeType).HasMaxLength(40).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(picture => picture.SeoFilename).HasMaxLength(300);
        builder.Property(p => p.ExternalUrl);
        base.Configure(builder);
    }
```

and I have exception:

`A key cannot be configured on 'PictureExt' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'Picture'. If you did not intend for 'Picture' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not included in a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation property on a type that is included in the model`

I understand what I did wrong, but I don't know how do it right.
Maybe something like this? https://stackify.com/new-in-net-core-2-1/#post-19576-_kaymrlea07yf

But how implement it?

Comment: net461 to netcore21 is not essential, the important is that looks like you are upgrading from EF6 to EF Core. And there are many differences between the two. Anyway, I noticed that in EF6 you configure `Picture` class while in EF Core you configure `PictureEx` class, why is that?

Comment: @IvanStoev The answer to your question I found buried in a GitHub issue, not sure what it means though! =P "The key must be defined on the base type because EF allows assigning derived entities to navigations configured with the base entity type.
If you don't need to track the base entity type you can just ignore it in 'OnModelCreating'"  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3863

Comment: Here's the doc explaining how relational db's are handled with EF Core.  I need to actually read this before I can update my answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make sure you don't have a `DbSet<Picture>` or `DbSet<BaseEntity>` on your `DbContext`. If the following solution cannot apply to your situation, please update your question so we can update our answers accordingly. :)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using System;
using Xunit;

public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Can_add_PictureExt()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .Options;

        using (var ctx = new Context(options))
        {
            ctx.Add(new PictureExt());
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var ctx = new Context(options))
        {
            Assert.Single(ctx.PictureExt);
        }
    }
}
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<PictureExt> PictureExt { get; set; }

    //uncommenting any of the following DbSet will throw exception

    //public DbSet<Picture> Picture { get; set; }

    //public DbSet<BaseEntity> BaseEntity { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PictureExtConfiguration());
    }
}
public class PictureExtConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PictureExt>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PictureExt> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Picture");
        builder.HasKey(picture => picture.Id);
        builder.Property(picture =>
        picture.MimeType).HasMaxLength(40).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(picture => picture.SeoFilename).HasMaxLength(300);
        builder.Property(p => p.ExternalUrl);

        //commented out to simplify example
        //base.Configure(builder);
    }
}
public partial class PictureExt : Picture
{
    public virtual string ExternalUrl { get; set; }
}
public partial class Picture : BaseEntity
{
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public string SeoFilename { get; set; }
    public string AltAttribute { get; set; }
    public string TitleAttribute { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }

    //commented out to simplify example
    //public virtual PictureBinary PictureBinary { get; set; }
}
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One-line fix:

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PictureExt> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Picture");
    
    // turn off deriving
    builder.HasBaseType((Type) null);

    builder.HasKey(picture => picture.Id);
    builder.Property(picture => 
    picture.MimeType).HasMaxLength(40).IsRequired();
    builder.Property(picture => picture.SeoFilename).HasMaxLength(300);
    builder.Property(p => p.ExternalUrl);
    base.Configure(builder);
}
```